# Is there a way to get a large amount of JSON from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, t-sql, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to get JSON out of a Microsoft SQL Server, and in order to communicate with my ASP.NET Core backend, I can only seem to use the max size permitted by an `NVARCHAR` which is up to 8,000 characters. But I need to grab a list of tens of thousands of characters of JSON.

```
var @params = new SqlParameter[] {
            new SqlParameter("@returnVal", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8000) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output },
            new SqlParameter("@ID", libraryID)
};

await this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("SET @returnVal = (SELECT * FROM Rates WHERE LibraryID=@ID FOR JSON AUTO)", @params);
return @params[0].Value as string;
```

I expect the output to be 8,000 characters with the above code because that seems to be a SQL limitation. Is there a way to get all the data back?

My goal is to attempt to download, as JSON, a large chunk of data from the database without having to map it to POCO's and then serialize it with a third party JSON library.

Thanks!

Comment: NVARCHAR(MAX) size is 2GB. `new SqlParameter("@returnVal", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda You are correct, using -1 means I don't have to guess at a size or assume 8000 like I had. You should make this an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data type is able to store up to 2GB.

You should set the size of NVarChar as `-1`:

```
new SqlParameter("@returnVal", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, change your field type and/or use the correct ADO.NET parameter type to bind the data.

Traditionally I would use a ***TEXT*** type but that is deprecated nowadays so you can use:

```
NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Comment: I have used that to success on the SQL side, but @LukaszSzozda answer in the comments makes the .NET side work for any size, even large batches.